ValueError: numpy.dtype size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 96 from C header, got 88 from PyObject
MRE
pip install pandas==2.1.1 numpy==2.0.0

Python 3.10 on Google Colab
Output
Collecting pandas==2.1.1
  Downloading pandas-2.1.1-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (12.3 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 12.3/12.3 MB 44.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting numpy==2.0.0
  Using cached numpy-2.0.0-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (19.3 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.8.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from pandas==2.1.1) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2020.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from pandas==2.1.1) (2023.4)
Requirement already satisfied: tzdata>=2022.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from pandas==2.1.1) (2024.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.8.2->pandas==2.1.1) (1.16.0)
Installing collected packages: numpy, pandas
  Attempting uninstall: numpy
    Found existing installation: numpy 1.26.4
    Uninstalling numpy-1.26.4:
      Successfully uninstalled numpy-1.26.4
  Attempting uninstall: pandas
    Found existing installation: pandas 2.0.3
    Uninstalling pandas-2.0.3:
      Successfully uninstalled pandas-2.0.3

Successfully installed numpy-2.0.0 pandas-2.1.1

When I do :
import pandas

I get this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/colab_kernel_launcher.py", line 37, in <module>
    ColabKernelApp.launch_instance()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 992, in launch_instance
    app.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 619, in start
    self.io_loop.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 195, in start
    self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 603, in run_forever
    self._run_once()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1909, in _run_once
    handle._run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/events.py", line 80, in _run
    self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 685, in <lambda>
    lambda f: self._run_callback(functools.partial(callback, future))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 738, in _run_callback
    ret = callback()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 825, in inner
    self.ctx_run(self.run)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 786, in run
    yielded = self.gen.send(value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 361, in process_one
    yield gen.maybe_future(dispatch(*args))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 234, in wrapper
    yielded = ctx_run(next, result)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 261, in dispatch_shell
    yield gen.maybe_future(handler(stream, idents, msg))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 234, in wrapper
    yielded = ctx_run(next, result)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 539, in execute_request
    self.do_execute(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 234, in wrapper
    yielded = ctx_run(next, result)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 302, in do_execute
    res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 539, in run_cell
    return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2975, in run_cell
    result = self._run_cell(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3030, in _run_cell
    return runner(coro)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/IPython/core/async_helpers.py", line 78, in _pseudo_sync_runner
    coro.send(None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3257, in run_cell_async
    has_raised = await self.run_ast_nodes(code_ast.body, cell_name,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3473, in run_ast_nodes
    if (await self.run_code(code, result,  async_=asy)):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3553, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-1-38d4b0363d82>", line 1, in <cell line: 1>
    import pandas
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from pandas.compat import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/compat/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from pandas.compat.pyarrow import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/compat/pyarrow.py", line 8, in <module>
    import pyarrow as pa
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pyarrow/__init__.py", line 65, in <module>
    import pyarrow.lib as _lib
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
AttributeError: _ARRAY_API not found
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-38d4b0363d82> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 import pandas

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/_libs/__init__.py in <module>
     16 import pandas._libs.pandas_parser  # noqa: E501 # isort: skip # type: ignore[reportUnusedImport]
     17 import pandas._libs.pandas_datetime  # noqa: F401,E501 # isort: skip # type: ignore[reportUnusedImport]
---> 18 from pandas._libs.interval import Interval
     19 from pandas._libs.tslibs import (
     20     NaT,

interval.pyx in init pandas._libs.interval()

ValueError: numpy.dtype size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 96 from C header, got 88 from PyObject


I found a solution for now:
I need to downgrade numpy to version 1.26.4
pip install numpy==1.26.4

or
pip install "numpy<2"

Restart session after downgrading numpy

Was able to successfully import pandas.


Related  git : https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/26710
